# Estimate for $\sum_{n > x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^2}$

Tags: analytic-number-theory, estimation

I am dealing with the term $\sum_{n \le x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^2}$ (where $x \to \infty$). Here, $\mu$ denotes the Möbius function. Writing $D_\mu (s) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}$ for the associated Dirichlet series, I can rewrite this as

$
\sum_{n \le x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^2}
= D_\mu(2) - \sum_{n > x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^2}
= \frac{6}{\pi^2} - \sum_{n > x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^2}.
$

Now I wonder, how small is the last sum? I am aware that

$
\lvert \sum_{n > x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^2} \rvert
\ll \sum_{n > x} \frac{1}{n^2}
\ll \frac{1}{x},
$

but can I do better? If not, is it possible to show $\lvert \sum_{n > x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^2} \rvert \gg \frac{1}{x}$?

Comment: So $D_{\mu}(s)=\frac{1}{\zeta (s)}$ for $\Re(s)>1$.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I'm seeking to bound the absolute value of that sum. This was badly formulated in the last sentence. So yes, I had already incorporated your suggestion in my thoughts. I'll try to make that clearer.

Comment: i think this is just the prime number theorem and partial summation - this gives you a saving $e(-c\sqrt \log x)$ on your estimate and there's not much more available

Comment: it depends on what is the order of the Mertens function, $M(x)=\sum_{n \le x}\mu(n)$, since by (dyadic) partial summation if $M(x)=O(x^{\alpha})$ we can easily get $ \sum_{n > x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^2}=O(x^{\alpha-2})$; in particular the OP question depends on a quantitive form of RH and of course $\lvert \sum_{n > x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^2} \rvert \gg \frac{1}{x}$ (for infinitely many $x \to \infty$)  would imply RH false and the supremum of the real part of the zeroes to be $1$

Comment: (@conrad oh, am i overlooking something with my comment then?)

Comment: @tomos no you are perfectly correct that as of now we do not know better than $M(x)=o(x)$ with whatever logarithmic improvement from the best known PNT error, so we cannot do better than $1/x$ with current knowledge; but the fact that $ \sum_{n > x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^2} <<  \frac{1}{x}$ tells us only that the true order of the sum is somewhere between $x^{-1}$ and $x^{-3/2}$ (give or take some logarithmic powers)

Comment: (ah ye sorry misunderstood something in your comment initially... i agree with it all)

Comment: @tomos Right now, I'm trying to wrap my head around the relation between zeros of $\zeta$ and the growth of $M(x) = \sum_{n \le x} \mu(n)$. I use the asymptotic version of Perron's formula and obtain that $M(x) \approx \int_{c-iT}^{c+iT} \frac{x^s}{s \zeta(s)} \dd s$. Since the integrand is holomorphic where $s \zeta(s)$ does not vanish, I can shift the integral to the line $[\lambda - iT, \lambda + iT]$ with $\lambda = 1 - \frac{\delta}{\log T}$ ($\delta$ coming from a zero-free region of $\zeta$). But to estimate this integral, I need a lower bound for $\zeta$. Can you help me?

Comment: @tomos You mentioned that PNT and Partial Summation are helpful. Is that a different approach than Perron's formula and, if so, how would we do that?

Comment: you're doing it right. you can find lower bounds for zeta in that region in any analytic number theory text book. if you don't have access, google something like "proof of prime number theorem lecture notes" and look for some which do it with error term. if you still can't find anything i'll google myself later and give you a concrete link

Comment: @tonos That would be helpful; or if you could point out a concrete lower bound for $\zeta(s)$. All I know are upper bounds.

Comment: @NerdOnTour The Perron formula approach requires estimates for $1/\zeta(s)$, which is also used to prove the bounds for $M(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Some comments have already pointed out that the decay of $\sum_{x \le n} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^2}$ is related to the growth of the "Mertens function"

$$M(x) = \sum_{n \le x} \mu(n).$$

I have taken the time now to make this precise. In particular, we will see in the end why it is probably not easy to prove/disprove

$$\lvert \sum_{N < n} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^2} \rvert \gg \frac{1}{N}$$

(which I had hoped when I asked the question).

Let us denote (for real numbers $y \le x$)

$$M(y, x) = \sum_{y \le n \le x} \mu(n),$$

so that $M(x) = M(1, x)$. Then, for integers $N < N'$, a partial summation yields

$$\sum_{N < n \le N'} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^2}
= M(N+1, N') \cdot \frac{1}{N'^2} + 2 \int_{N+1}^{N'} M(N+1, t) \cdot \frac{1}{t^3} \text{d} t.
$$

Since we have $\lvert M(N+1, N') \rvert \le N' - N \le N'$, the first summand goes to $0$ as $N' \to \infty$. Therefore, taking limits on both sides gives (for $N \in \mathbb{N}$ still fixed) the formula

$$
\sum_{N < n} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^2}
= 2 \int_N^\infty M(N+1, t) \cdot \frac{1}{t^3} \text{d} t \\
= 2 \int_N^\infty M(t) \cdot \frac{1}{t^3} \text{d} t - 2 \int_N^\infty M(N) \cdot \frac{1}{t^3} \text{d} t \\
= 2 \int_N^\infty M(t) \cdot \frac{1}{t^3} \text{d} t + M(N) \cdot \frac{1}{N^2}.
$$

So if we have $M(N) \ll N^\alpha$ for some $\alpha < 1$,  then the right summand and the integral both evaluate to $\ll N^{\alpha - 2}$.

It is clear that $M(N) \ll N$ from the definition of the Mertens function. So this gives an alternative proof for $\sum_{N < n} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^2} \ll \frac{1}{N}$. And if we knew that the Riemannian $\zeta$-function has no zeros in $\Re(s) > \alpha$ for an $\alpha < 1$, then we could show (with a long computation, and using Perron's formula) $M(N) \ll N^\alpha$.

This also proves [Conrad](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/298272/conrad)'s remark in the comments above: If $\lvert \sum_{N < n} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^2} \rvert \gg \frac{1}{N}$, then no such $\alpha < 1$ exists, i.e. the Riemann hypothesis would be false.